# Creating maps in QGIS from Drone Videos

Tags: qgis, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

If it is possible to create maps in QGIS from Drone Videos, then how do I do it?

I've found software like DroneDeploy but QGIS being so long in this race, I feel more reliable. I have drone video footage over a certain area. How can I make maps out of it?

Comment: The short answer is: yes, you can. For a more detailed answer, please substantiate your question: what exactly do you have, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: check this https://github.com/All4Gis/QGISFMV